# Read the value of <mat-option> angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-template

**HTML:**

```
  <mat-icon class="fab fa-raspberry-pi"></mat-icon>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Rpi">
      <mat-option>Choose</mat-option>
      <mat-option *ngFor='let pi of myRpis' [(ngModel)]="RpiIp" ngDefaultControl [value]="pi.RPI_IP"
        (click)="getPins()">
        {{pi.LABEL}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

**Typescript:**
I have:

```
  RpiIp = '';
```

and

```
  getPins() {
    console.log(this.RpiIp);
    this.doneFetching = true;
  }
```

The console prints an empty value (the value do not change). Where is the error? why the value is not changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57331512/10537037) the correct answer looks like this:

```
 <mat-icon class="fab fa-raspberry-pi"></mat-icon>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="Rpi" [(value)]="RpiIp">
          <mat-option>Choose</mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor='let pi of myRpis' ngDefaultControl [value]="pi.RPI_IP" (click)="getPins()">
            {{pi.LABEL}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to place the ngModel on the `mat-select`, not on the `mat-option`

Answer (score 2):

**mat-select** will be containing the **mat-option**, so you have to use ngModel on mat-select.

Consider the below code:

```
<select . . . name="duration" [(ngModel)]="exercisePlan.duration"> 
<option *ngFor="let duration of durations" [value]="duration.value">{{duration.title}}</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Rpi" [(value)]="RpiIp">
    <mat-option>Choose</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor='let pi of myRpis'  ngDefaultControl [value]="pi.RPI_IP"
      (click)="getPins()">
      {{pi.LABEL}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

https://stackblitz.com/angular/dybkbybngme?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.ts

Comment: it is [(value)] instead of [(ngmodel)] so that it reads the [value] field

Answer (score 0):

```
    <mat-icon class="fab fa-raspberry-pi"></mat-icon>
    <mat-form-field>
       <mat-select placeholder="Rpi" >
         <mat-option>Choose</mat-option>
         <mat-option *ngFor='let pi of myRpis' ngDefaultControl [value]="pi.RPI_IP" (click)="getPins()">
          {{pi.LABEL}}
         </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```